# How to use the tree command to expand only selected folder(s)?

Tags: tree

I'm creating a script that generates a project folder into another folder along with some other module folders. I want to show how the generated project folder structure looks in the final tree but avoid the expansion of all other folders so the visualization is clearer.

For instance, this is what happens if I do `tree` alone:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cfg
│   ├── hsm_engine_cfg.h
│   ├── osal_rtos_defs.h
│   ├── system_events.h
│   ├── system_tasks.h
│   ├── system_trace_cfg.h
│   └── test_delete_cfg.h
├── hsm-engine
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── component.mk
│   ├── docs
│   │   ├── HSM-Engine.mdj
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── choiceState.png
│   │   │   ├── inconditionalTransition.png
│   │   │   ├── inconditionalTransitionTwoEvents.png
│   │   │   ├── inconditionalTransitionTwoEventsOneGuard.png
│   │   │   ├── inconditionalTransitionWithActions.png
│   │   │   ├── simpleStateEmpty.png
│   │   │   ├── simpleStateEntry.png
│   │   │   ├── simpleStateEntryDo.png
│   │   │   └── simpleStateEntryExit.png
│   │   └── readme.md
│   ├── hsm_engine.c
│   ├── hsm_engine_cfg.h.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── hsm_engine.h
│   │   ├── hsme_history_entry_struct_macro.h
│   │   ├── hsme_hsm_handler_macro.h
│   │   ├── hsme_state_transitions_macro.h
│   │   ├── hsme_states_array_macro.h
│   │   └── hsme_states_enum_macro.h
│   └── tools
│       ├── hsm-parser
│       └── hsm-parser.exe
├── osal
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── FreeRTOSConfig.h.txt
│   ├── Kconfig
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── component.mk
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── osal.h
│   │   ├── osal_events.h
│   │   ├── osal_task_sync.h
│   │   └── osal_tasks.h
│   ├── osal_events.c
│   ├── osal_rtos_defs.h.txt
│   ├── osal_task_sync.c
│   ├── osal_tasks.c
│   ├── system_events.h.txt
│   └── system_tasks.h.txt
├── test-delete
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── test_delete_api.h
│   │   └── test_delete_event_id.h
│   ├── test_delete.c
│   ├── test_delete.h
│   └── test_delete_cfg.h.txt
├── test-gtest
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   └── test_delete_testsuite.cpp
├── test_delete_main.c
└── trace
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Kconfig
    ├── README.md
    ├── component.mk
    ├── include
    │   ├── colors.h
    │   └── system_trace.h
    ├── system_trace.c
    └── system_trace_cfg.h.txt
```

As you can see, that's a lot of output and it is not clear to see the created folder in which I'm interested which is `test-delete`.

I tried with `tree -P 'test-delete*|test_delete*'` is really close to what I need. It gives:

```
.
├── cfg
│   └── test_delete_cfg.h
├── hsm-engine
│   ├── docs
│   │   └── images
│   ├── include
│   └── tools
├── osal
│   └── include
├── test-delete
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── test_delete_api.h
│   │   └── test_delete_event_id.h
│   ├── test_delete.c
│   ├── test_delete.h
│   └── test_delete_cfg.h.txt
├── test-gtest
│   └── test_delete_testsuite.cpp
├── test_delete_main.c
└── trace
    └── include
```

But it is still expanding all the folders which is not ideal. I'm looking for the correct `tree` configuration so I have this:

```
.
├── cfg
│   └── test_delete_cfg.h
├── hsm-engine
├── osal
├── test-delete
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── test_delete_api.h
│   │   └── test_delete_event_id.h
│   ├── test_delete.c
│   ├── test_delete.h
│   └── test_delete_cfg.h.txt
├── test-gtest
├── test_delete_main.c
└── trace
```

As you can see here. only `cfg` and `test-delete` folders are expanded, the rest is not. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your file names don't contain newline characters, you could always do:

```
find . -path '*test[-_]delete*' | tree --fromfile /dev/stdin
```

Or

```
find . | grep 'test[-_]delete' | tree --fromfile /dev/stdin
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for multiple folders with different names? For example, I want to get the tree structure for `cruises` and `cruise_control`, but my command only returns those for `cruises` : ```find . \(-type f -and -path '*cruises*' -or -path '*cruise_control*'\) | tree --fromfile /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal to find files with 'test-delete' in the name, it would be better to use `find`:

```
find . -name test-delete*
```

Comment: no, it is not to find files but rather to show the folder tree structure